# Is it always possible to use Chasles to decompose an integral?

Tags: integration, analysis, soft-question, definite-integrals

Well, I'm in "[classe préparatoire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classe_pr%C3%A9paratoire_aux_grandes_%C3%A9coles)" and I always learn that if f is a continuous fonction integrable on [a,b] and if c is in [a,b] then with Chasles relation we have :

$$
\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_a^c f(x) dx + \int_c^b f(x) dx
$$

I would like to know if there are some functions which are integrable on [a,b] but not on [a,c] and [c,b] ?

Maybe in infinit dimension? Are possible also in finite dimension?

Thank's before for your answer ! :D

Shadock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different definitions of *integrable*. Since you're not yet in university, the standard definition would be the Riemann integral.

*Claim*: A bounded Riemann integrable function on $[a,b]$ is Riemann integrable on any subinterval of $[a,b]$.

The basic point is that Riemann integrability has to do with chopping your interval into tiny pieces and seeing if the *upper Riemann sums* and the *lower Riemann sums* converge to the same number as you subdivide more and more. So one extra split at $c$ will not make a difference.

*Discussion*:

Let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function.

Given a partition $P = \{x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ of $[a,b]$ with $a = x_0 \leq x_1 \leq \cdots \leq x_n = b$, we set $\Delta x_i = x_i - x_{i-1}$ and

$U(P,f) = \sum_{i=1}^n \Delta x_i \sup_{x \in [x_{i-1},x_i]} f(x)\ $ (the upper Riemann sum)

$L(P,f) = \sum_{i=1}^n \Delta x_i \inf_{x \in [x_{i-1},x_i]} f(x)\ $ (the lower Riemann sum)

(Here $\sup$ is the supremum, or least upper bound (think: max), and $\inf$ is the infimum, or greatest lower bound (think: min).)

Then we say a function $f$, bounded on $[a,b]$, is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, or $f \in \mathcal{R}([a,b])$, if $\inf_{\mathrm{partitions}\ P} U(P,f) = \sup_{\mathrm{partitions}\ P} L(P,f)$, in which case this value is what we define to be the value of the integral $\int_a^b f\, dx$.

*Claim*: $f\in \mathcal{R}([a,b]) \Longrightarrow f \in \mathcal{R}([c,d])$ for $a \leq c \leq d \leq b$.

This claim follows from the following theorems. See Rudin, *Principals of Mathematical Analysis* for proofs of these (they're not long).

We say $P^*$ is a *refinement* of $P$ if $P^* \supset P$.

*Theorem 1*: If $P^*$ is a refinement of $P$ then $L(P,f) \leq L(P^*,f)$ and $U(P^*,f) \leq U(P,f)$.

That is, splitting up our interval at more points can only help bring the upper and lower Riemann sums closer together.

*Theorem 2*: $f \in \mathcal{R}([a,b])$ if and only if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a partition $P$ such that $U(P,f) - L(P,f) < \epsilon$.

That is, the function is Riemann integrable if and only if for any $\epsilon$ we can find a partition whose upper and lower Riemann sums are within $\epsilon$ of each other. Together with Theorem 1, we can use this to show $f$ Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ implies $f$ Riemann integrable on $[c,d]$.

*Proof of Claim*: Suppose $f \in \mathcal{R}([a,b])$. We aim to prove $f \in \mathcal{R}([c,d])$. By Theorem 2 above, it suffices to show there exists a partition $P$ of $[c,d]$ such that $U(P,f) - L(P,f) < \epsilon$.

We have, by Theorem 2 and $f \in \mathcal{R}([a,b])$, that there exists a partition $Q$ of $[a,b]$ such that $U(Q,f) - L(Q,f) < \epsilon$.

Then by Theorem 1 if we let $Q^* = Q \cup \{c,d\}$ we have $U(Q^*,f) - L(Q^*,f) \leq U(Q,f) - L(Q,f) < \epsilon$.

Then we let $P = Q^* \cap [c,d]$. By considering the definitions of $U(P,f)$ and $L(P,f)$ we see that $U(P,f) - L(P,f) = \sum_{i=1}^n \Delta x_i (\sup_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]} f(x) - \inf_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]} f(x))$ is a sum of nonnegative terms, as is $U(Q^*,f) - L(Q^*,f)$, and each term of the former appears in the sum for the latter.

Thus $U(P,f) - L(P,f) \leq U(Q^*,f) - L(Q^*,f) < \epsilon$.

Thus we've shown the condition in Theorem 2 for the interval $[c,d]$, and so we have $f \in \mathcal{R}([c,d])$.

Comment: Well thank you for your answer but contrary to you, my grade level in maths is really "poor" and I don't understand all you write. But I try to do it, for example what is $R([a,b])$ ? And when some people in this site upvote your answer you will win the +50 :) and so is yes or no the answer of my question because I really don't understand :P

Comment: The answer is no, every function that's integrable on $[a,b]$ is integrable on $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$. I'll edit my answer to be more understandable. The notation $\mathcal{R}([a,b])$ is what I'm using for the set of Riemann integrable functions on the interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: OK and an other question more specific, is it possible to find an easy function which verify this?

Comment: what is a refinement ?

Comment: The statement is: For all functions $f$ which are integrable on $[a,b]$, the function $f$ is also integrable on $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$. So it doesn't make sense to verify this with one function, since it's a "for all" statement. To check it on an example is pretty boring: write down your favorite integrable function (let's say $f(x) = x$) and it's integrable on $[a,b]$ as well as $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$.

Comment: Refine means divide your interval at even more points. So if you started partitioning $[0,1]$ by $\{0, .2, .6, 1\}$, then you could refine it to more pieces, partitioning it at $\{0, .2, .3, .6, .9, 1\}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19946/discussion-between-shadock-and-aes).